# SORT(DISTINCT) :Is it because of Kitchen sink queries?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sort-operator, performance-tuning, query-performance

One of the SQL queries I am working on is slow in performance. I have been trying to fix it for the last two days, unsuccessfully. The query is generated from an application (Linq to sql -EFF), and based on the user search criteria, it passes parameters to the query.

I looked into the execution plan and I see sort operations. One of the sort operation is `SORT(DISTINCT)`. I checked the query and I found some `order by` in the query. Removing `order by` didn't help, and I dont have a `DISTINCT` in the query. On checking the properties of the `SORT(DISTINCT)` it is not showing the field on which it is doing sort. I have attached the screenshot of that.

After doing some research I learned that `OR` in `where` conditions can generate `SORT` operations as the `MERGE` required some kind of sort, and I do have `OR` in `where` conditions which looks like:

```
where (column1 = @param1) OR (column1 IS NULL) OR (@param1 IS NULL)
```

Someone suggested me in an earlier post that, this are "Kitchen sink" queries and it will cause performance issues.

Is there anyone who had to deal with similar situation? Any solutions?

[image: SORT(DISTINCT)]

Comment: Aaron Bertrand has a lovely article for this: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/

Comment: I have already read that article and it is very much informative.But i couldn't find any info `SORT(DISTINCT)` anywhere and why is occurring. I don't even have a `DISTINCT` in my query.That is the reason i posted this in here.

Comment: Is the @param1 is null correct?  What would be the reason for that in a query?

Comment: @Aaron :What do you mean by null correct.When generating SQL query using `Linq-SQL` ,i assume that null checking is getting generated.Other reason i think is,the query has multiple search criteria and if one of the search criteria is null,it should be ignored and move on.

Comment: Since it’s not used to filter on any of the data in the query when param1 is null it is equivalent to having no where clause since the where clause is or based

Comment: I guess my question is why `SORT(DISTINCT)` is getting generated or of it is there how can i remove it